# Server 2003 on domain wont let domain user have local profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, terminal-server, user-profile

I have a few servers that are acting in this behavior, you log in and always get put into a temporary profile. The server is licensed for TS. The user I am testing with has local admin rights so it doesn't seem to be a permission issue on the server.

I'll first get a message that the users roaming profile cannot be found, even though we dont use roaming profiles. I then get another message immediately after saying a local profile could not be loaded, so it will only use a temp profile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the Group Policy Editor for the machine (gpedit.msc)
Computer Config > Admin Templates > System > User Profiles > Only Allow Local Profile - Enable.

This has been an outstanding issue and headache of mine for months... Yet a stupid fix, hopefully it helps someone else out!

Answer (score 1):

Check your TS GPO for a roaming profile setting. The setting is at:

Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Terminal Services>Set path for TS Roaming Profiles

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure their profile has been deleted and nothing exists at  `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%` and `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%.%DOMAN%`
2. Open up `regedit`
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
4. Remove the key for the users with the problems.  The key will be based on the users Security identifiers like `S-1-5-21-3141592-6535897932-3846644798-1649`.

   - You can look at the value for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3141592-6535897932-3846644798-1649\ProfileImagePath` to help you figure out which profile is which.

Comment: I did this, and now when i log on to the server, i get the normal log on screen.. fill in user name and password, and then the rdc connection ends w and w/o console switch applied as soon as i click the button.

Comment: just tried another user as well, this user I get the same exact results as before. Trying to access roaming profile even though there isnt one, then cant find or create local profile either and logs on with temp.

Comment: Hrm, that is unusual.  Are you sure the user doesn't have roaming profile settings applied to their account?  Can you check the eventlog after a login, there should be some errors being logged.  I do know the above helped fix a situation that I was having that I believe was similar.

Comment: I get the following errors in the event log (user and server name scrambled):

Comment: Event Type:        Error
Event Source:    Userenv
Event Category:                None
Event ID:              1521
Date:                     3/10/2010
Time:                     1:14:01 PM
User:                     zxzbz\zcbzcbzb
Computer:          zccb-zcbz-zcbzc
Description:
Windows cannot locate the server copy of your roaming profile and is attempting to log you on with your local profile. Changes to the profile will not be copied to the server when you logoff. Possible causes of this error include network problems or insufficient security rights.  DETAIL - The network name cannot be found.

Comment: Event Type:        Error
Event Source:    Userenv
Event Category:                None
Event ID:              1511
Date:                     3/10/2010
Time:                     1:14:04 PM
User:                     czbcz\zcbzcb
Computer:          zcbczbzcbzcbzb
Description:
Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

Comment: No roaming profile is designated for the user in AD